# Where is Database.serialize() mentioned? Node-SQLite

Tags: node.js, node-sqlite3

Why isn't the `Database.serialize()` method mentioned in the [Node-SQLite API](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API)?

Answer (score 0):

They have a page about it in the documentation, available at:

https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/Control-Flow

It's the second link on the documentation wiki:
https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki